# How to get the list of user ID who click likes and comments in Twitter by Twitter API, like the picture below

Tags: api, twitter

[image: User list who clicks the like button]

Hi, I want to get the user list in one Twitter post as picture shown. but I didn't find the API which I can get this kind of data on Twitter. Is there anyone know how can I get this data. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [official API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) does not include that functionality.

You will find that there are lots of actions which are available on the official website & apps which are not allowed in the API.

Sorry.